# Identifying documents associated with mahout clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mahout

It's fairly easy to create doc vectors and cluster using apache mahout . Executing a clusterdump allows the user to view the terms associated with the individual clusters. However, how can I identify the documents that belong to each cluster ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would think, for each document, find the Euclidean distance of it's vector with each cluster center, and assign it to closest cluster.

Comment: Depends on the clustering algorithm, obviously. Squared Euclidean is correct for plain k-means only.

Comment: Thanks, but does the mahout API provide any methods / set of methods to accomplish this (finding the docs associated with a cluster) ? I just came across this snippet on this blogpost that I should probably try http://bickson.blogspot.com/2011/09/understanding. This prints each doc and its respective cluster . Code snippet at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4998621

Comment: It's a fairly easy method to implement, dunno about Mahout in particular.